# I have combinations of four numbers and I do not want any repeated combinations to show. java

Tags: java

2 4 6 12 and 4 2 6 12 are technically not a combination as the both contain the same values in different order, so only show 2 4 6 12

I'm not sure how to remove combinations that have the same numbers.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class drawingStraws {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    int sum = 0;
    int hour =0;
    int hourTwo=0;
    int hourThree=0;
    int hourFour=0;
    int x,m,d,f;
    System.out.println(" straw drawing program!\n straw1\tstarw2\tstraw3\tstraw4");

    for(x=1;x<=14;x++)
    {
        for(m=1;m<=14;m++)
        {
            for(d=1;d<=14;d++)
            {
                for(f=1;f<=14;f++)
                {
                    sum=0;
                        hour=x*x;
                    sum=sum+hour;   
                    hourTwo=m*m;
                    sum=sum+hourTwo;
                    hourThree=d*d;
                    sum=sum+hourThree;
                    hourFour=f*f;
                    sum=sum+hourFour;
                    if(sum==200)
                    {
                        if (x==m||x==d||x==f || m==x||m==d||m==f || d==x||d==f||d==m || f==m||f==d||f==x)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        System.out.println(x+"\t"+m+"\t"+d+"\t"+f);
                        }
                    }

                }
             } 
          }
        }

      }

    }
```

this output will show (2 4 6 12 , 4 12 6 2 , 12 6 4 2 etc.)
this is the problem----- the players would draw straws . A straw would be marked with a single number indicating both how many days the player must work and how many hours each day. For example, a player drawing a straw marked with a 3 would work for 3 hours a day for 3 days, making a total of 9 hours. The lazy player convinced the others to agree with this scheme and through trickery drew the best straw.

The problem is to determine all of the possible ways to divide up the work according to this scheme.

You will have to use nested loops to test all of the possible combinations of 4 numbers that will result in exactly 200 hours of work.

Couple of notes:

1. There cannot be a 0 straw which indicates 0 days for 0 hours.
2. Each straw must be unique so they cannot repeat values.
3. Since this is combination you cannot have repeated results

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you simplify your goal, because I don't know what you want to accomplish only by reading your code. It seems like your problem is a variant of the [3 sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM). A classic way to solve this kind of problem is using sorting, than the input [2 4 6 12] and [4 2 6 12] would be the same after sorted.

Comment: @amey91 I can't have enough reputation to comment under your post,so i reply your post here. TreeSet is not an option because the element Havocshot wanna compare is an array not just a integer. So the TreeSet may not work since your can't have an array as a key if your not override the hashcode method of the array object.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you have a complex problem, there's already a library for that.  Check out [Apache Commons Math](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/util/Combinations.html).

```
// Instantiate the Combinations; we want numbers up to 14 in sets of 4
Combinations combinationSet = new Combinations(14, 4);

// Iterate over each of the combinations, represented as int[]s
Iterator<int[]> iterator = combinationSet.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.print("[ ");
    for(int number : iterator.next()) {
        System.out.print(number + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}
```

Comment: This seems like a homework problem, so using external libraries is a big nono.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Yeah, I gave the answer before the OP edited all the homework dump in there.

Answer (score 0):

Jade points out an easy way to solve your problem. However, sorting takes O(n logn) time and computing it over m sets will make the complexity worse.

Since you are using Java, I would advise you to use [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). It :

1. has an access time of O(logn)
2. does not allow duplicate elements
3. allows you to iterate over the elements in natural order to compare them and determine equality

The resulting complexity would just be O(logn + n) = O(n)